# how to read seismic data from azure blob storage

Tags: python, pandas, azure-blob-storage

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

import os

STORAGEACCOUNTURL = ""

STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = ""

CONTAINERNAME = ""

BLOBNAME = ""

blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(

account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)

blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(

CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME)

blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()

data = blob_data.readall()

print(data)
```

ERROR:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Getting error while execute it. Kindly guide how to read seismic data(more than 1gb) file using azure blob storage using python

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I observed that you are receiving this error due to the presence of non-utf8 characters present in your file. Make sure you decode the data before printing.

```
decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')
```

Below is the complete code that's working for me.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os

STORAGEACCOUNTURL = "<Your_Storage_URL>"
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = "<Your_Storage_Account>"
CONTAINERNAME = "<Your_Container>"
BLOBNAME = "<Your_Blob_Name>"

blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(
account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME)
blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
data = blob_data.readall()

decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')

print(decoded_data)
```

***RESULTS:***

[image]

Comment: still got same error